# How to easily move an entire drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this drawing below. How can I easily move the entire tikzpicture somewhere else ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I mean by easy should be like

```
\begin{tikzpicture, origin=1.0,1.0}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `node` should be the answer!

Comment: Could you please add your use-case? It is hard to tell how to shift this picture (tikz has options for shift), if we do not know in which context it should be shifted.

Comment: Not sure what it means to move the `tikzpicture`. But if you want to move something in the picture use `\begin{scope}[shift={(<x>,<y>)}] <content to be moved> \end{scope}` where the shift amount is `<x>` in the x-direction and `<y>` in the y-direction.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `scope` environment with options indicating a `[shift={(1,1)}]` translation
Your code becomes so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat similar to [Raven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447914/121799), but perhaps less brutal and more accurate (since nodes have a width). Technically it extends the bounding box, but in a document (other than standalone) it does shift the picture. This thing does not work well with overlay.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{shift entire picture/.style n args={2}{execute at end picture={
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpx}{sign(#1)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpy}{sign(#2)}
\ifnum\tmpx=1
  \ifnum\tmpy=1
   \path[use as bounding box] ([xshift=-#1,yshift=-#2]current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
(current bounding box.north east);
  \else
   \path[use as bounding box] ([xshift=-#1]current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
([yshift=-#2]current bounding box.north east);
  \fi
\else  
  \ifnum\tmpy=1
   \path[use as bounding box] ([yshift=-#2]current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
([xshift=-#1]current bounding box.north east);
  \else
   \path[use as bounding box] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
([xshift=-#1,yshift=-#2]current bounding box.north east); 
  \fi
\fi}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift entire picture={3cm}{-5cm}]
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \ifnum\x=0
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \else
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,0.1,4)  (\x ,0.9,4) -- (\x ,1.1,4)
    (\x ,1.9,4) -- (\x ,2.1,4) (\x ,2.9,4) -- (\x ,3.1,4)
    (\x ,3.9,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \fi
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \ifnum\x=0
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \else
    \draw (\x,4,0) -- (\x,4,0.1)  (\x,4,0.9) -- (\x,4,1.1)
    (\x,4,1.9) -- (\x,4,2.1) (\x,4,2.9) -- (\x,4,3.1)
    (\x,4,3.9) -- (\x,4,4);
    \fi
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't the problem of the node having a width be overcome if setting the node's shape to be a `coordinate`?

Comment: @Raven Yes, of course. But even then your method is only accurate if you place the coordinate at some distance relative to the bounding box. The bounding box also takes into account the line widths, not just the coordinates involved in the paths,

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the most elegant solution but it works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Create "shifting node" that shifts all following coordinates by (5,6)
\node at (-5,-6) {};
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This basically works by adding an invisible node to where the origin lays after the picture has been "shifted". That way there is some content in that area preventing it from being clipped away by `tikz` (which I assume is happening when simply using the `shift` option for the whole image).

Further clarification on the `shift`-option as provided by @TeXnician in the comments:
[The `shift` option] does shift the coordinate origin (transform every coordinate). As the bounding box is trimmed you will still not notice it in an ordinary context (it is handy sometimes, though).

Comment: This way of extending the bounding box is possible, but does it really do the same as "shift" (have you tried the option)?

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't do anything at all (at least when passed to the `tikzpicture`-environment) which is why I even came up with adding the invisible reference point...

Comment: Well, that's not entirely right. It does shift the coordinate origin (transform every coordinate). As the bounding box is trimmed you will still not notice it in an ordinary context (it is handy sometimes, though). I just asked, because your last sentence is based on an assumption.

Comment: Yeah that is what I figured and it's actually what I tried to say in my last sentence. I will integrate your comment in my answer in order to avoid future confusion.